# Can't install StarUML in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: dpkg, staruml, ubuntu-16.04

I’m using ubuntu 16.04 - 64 bit. I tried to install Start UML with .deb file and got this message from Ubuntu Software:

```
This software comes from a 3rd party and may contain non-free components
```

Then I trying to install with dpkg, and got this:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i StarUML-v2.7.0-64-bit.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package staruml.
(Reading database ... 212003 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack StarUML-v2.7.0-64-bit.deb ...
Unpacking staruml (2.7.0) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of staruml:
 staruml depends on libgcrypt11 (>= 1.4.5); however:
  Package libgcrypt11 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package staruml (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 staruml
```

Could you help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

1. Download libgcrypt11_1.5.3  from: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libgcrypt11_1.5.3-2ubuntu4.2_amd64.deb
2. Install lib with dpkg

   `sudo dpkg -i libgcrypt11_1.5.3-2ubuntu4.2_amd64.deb`
3. Install StarUML with dpkg

   `sudo dpkg -i StarUML-v2.7.0-64-bit.deb`

Answer (score 9):

Download

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libg/libgcrypt11/libgcrypt11_1.5.3-2ubuntu4_amd64.deb
```

Install lib with dpkg

```
sudo dpkg -i libgcrypt11_1.5.3-2ubuntu4_amd64.deb
```

Install StarUML with dpkg

```
sudo dpkg -i StarUML-v2.8.0-64-bit.deb
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding to this topic for Ubuntu 18.04:

1. Download libgcrypt11 from the provided link:

   https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libgcrypt11_1.5.3-2ubuntu4.2_amd64.deb
2. Now, install it with the command:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i libgcrypt11_1.5.3-2ubuntu4.2_amd64.deb
   ```
3. Now, we have to install another dependency, libcurl3. Run the command:

   ```
   sudo apt install libcurl3
   ```
4. Now, proceed with the installation of StarUML:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i StarUML-v2.8.1-64-bit.deb
   ```

   Note that the file name will change depending on StarUML version.

That's it. Worked like charm for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had this error when trying to install the Start UML installation before installing the libgcrypt11_1.5.3-2ubuntu4_amd64.deb package. If you complete the steps above, please run:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

with me it run

Answer (score 0):

To me I had to do the following steps:

**Installing the deb file using dpkg:**

```
sudo dpkg -i StarUML-v2.8.0-64-bit.deb
```

Followed by the `sudo apt-get install -f` command.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally you have to install libpango-1.0-0

```
sudo apt install libpango-1.0-0
```